# Autofac and Func factories

Tags: .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, autofac, caliburn.micro

I'm working on an application using Caliburn.Micro and Autofac.

In my composition root I'm now facing a problem with Autofac:
I have to inject the globally used IEventAggregator into my FirstViewModel, and a second IEventAggregator that has to be used only by this FirstViewModel and it's children.

My idea was to make the second one be injected as `Owned<IEA>`, and it works, the container provides a different instance of IEA.

```cs
public FirstViewModel(
    IEventAggregator globalEA,
    IEventAggregator localEA,
    Func<IEventAggregator, SecondViewModel> secVMFactory) {}
```

The problem comes when I have to provide the event aggregators to the SecondViewModel.

To create the SecondViewModel I use a factory method as `Func<IEA, SecondVM>`.
The SecondViewModel's constructor is the following:

`public SecondViewModel(IEventAggregator globalEA, IEventAggregator localEA) {}`

I want the container to inject the first as the registered one, and the second will be the IEA parameter of the `Func<IEA, SecVM>`.

this is the function I registered in the container:

```cs
builder.Register<Func<IEventAggregator, SecondViewModel>>(
     c =>
         (ea) =>
         {
             return new SecondViewModel(
                 c.Resolve<IEventAggregator>(),
                 ea);
         }
);
```

but when it gets called by the `FirstViewModel` I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.

I can't understand where the problem is, can you help me please, what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are calling `secVMFactory` outside of your `FirstViewModel` constructor so by that time the ResolveOperation is disposed and in your factory method the `c.Resolve` will throw the exception.

Luckily the exception message is very descriptive and telling you what to do:

> When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c'
>   parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve
>   IComponentContext again from 'c'

So instead of calling `c.Resolve` you need to resolve the `IComponentContext` from `c` and use that in your factory func:

```cs
builder.Register<Func<IEventAggregator, SecondViewModel>>(c => {
     var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
     return ea => { 
          return new SecondViewModel(context.Resolve<IEventAggregator>(), ea); 
     };
});
```

Comment: haha I tried to do that but I put it the inner function, so i kept getting the same error! +1 one more question: should I do it in every registration in order to prevent any vm order instantiation refactoring?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, you can always `c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();` when you are registering a `Func` into the container or just do it only in the cases where you actually need to call `Resolve` in your factory.

Comment: You can read more about this problem in the post [The Curious Case of a Deadlock in Autofac](http://www.continuousimprover.com/2015/01/the-curious-case-of-deadlock-in-autofac.html)

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, it solved my problem! I just don't understand the solution completely. If c gets out of scope by the time we use the registered Func, how come context does not go out of scope? Thanks!