# Dependency injection in AutoMapper for custom classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I am having a Entity and Dto and trying to custom map those classes to have EmpUrl=baseurl+EmpPath.I am planning to get baseurl from configuration file and mapping via DI but getting below error:

*System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'MappingProfile'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.*

```
 public MyMappingProfile(IOptions <ApplicationSettings> applicationsettings)
        {
            CreateMap<Emp, EmpDto>()

            .ForMember(e => e.EmpUrl, e => e.MapFrom(src => applicationsettings.Value.BaseDomain + src.EmpPath));
             
        }
```

The class to register dependency is below:

```
public class MyModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public ApplicationModule(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {

            // Register Automapper profiles
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddMaps(typeof(MappingProfile).Assembly); });


config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        builder.Register(c => config)
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
            .As<IMapper>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    
            var settings = new ApplicationSettings();
            Configuration.Bind(settings);
            builder.RegisterInstance(Options.Create(settings));

        }
      
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder container)
        {
            container.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule(Configuration));                
           
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/141#issuecomment-1079914176) and [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#autofac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `MyMappingProfile` inherits from the `AutoMapper.Profile` class, there are a couple issues here:

1. The `cfg.AddMaps` method is called immediately during construction of the `MapperConfiguration` instance (per [AutoMapper v11.0.1 source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v11.0.1/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MapperConfiguration.cs#L114-L117)). This is during application startup loading of the `ApplicationModule` (not during lazy resolution of dependencies from the container at runtime). The `AddMaps` call, which creates a new instance of `MyMappingProfile`, is executed even before the `ApplicationSettings` are bound from configuration and added to the DI container.
2. Likely related to #1, the `cfg.AddMaps` method call uses .NET `System.Activator.CreateInstance` directly to instantiate the mapping profile (e.g. `MyMappingProfile`) and does not pass any arguments, which is why you're getting the "No parameterless constructor defined" error. This flow does not use the `serviceCtor` argument passed to the `MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper` method. (AutoMapper `MapperConfigurationExpression.AddMaps` calls `AddMapsCore`, which calls `AddProfile(Type)` per [v11.0.1 source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v11.0.1/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MapperConfigurationExpression.cs#L157))

One approach to resolve `IOptions<ApplicationSettings>` at runtime from the  DI container using AutoMapper is by using the service factory method (`serviceCtor`) passed to `MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper`.

The mapping profile could be something like:

```cs
public class MyMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Emp, EmpDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmpUrl, e => e.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, ctx) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.EmpPath))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var applicationSettings = (IOptions<ApplicationSettings>)ctx.Options.ServiceCtor(typeof(IOptions<ApplicationSettings>));
                return applicationSettings.Value.BaseDomain + src.EmpPath;
            }));
    }
}
```

To keep the mapping clean or reuse the logic, you could extract the inline `MapFrom` logic into a local method in the mapping profile class, a separate custom [Value Resolver (or Member Value Resolver)](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) used with `opt.MapFrom`, or a separate custom [Value Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html) used with `opt.ConvertUsing`. A custom converter or resolver can use dependencies injected via the constructor rather than using the `ResolutionContext` explicitly.

If you try only the mapping profile changes, then Autofac will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` with a message like `This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.` from this line:

```
var applicationSettings = (IOptions<ApplicationSettings>)ctx.Options.ServiceCtor(typeof(IOptions<ApplicationSettings>));
```

The solution is to change your `ApplicationModule.Load` from

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>()
    .CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
    .As<IMapper>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

to

```
builder.Register(c =>
    {
        var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        var mapperConfig = c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>();
        return mapperConfig.CreateMapper(ctx.Resolve);
    })
    .As<IMapper>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This is based on personal experience and is also covered by other SO questions such as [This resolve operation has already ended. Autofac, Automapper & IMemberValueResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53047850/). Dennis Doomen gives a good explanation of this Autofac design nuance in [The curious case of a deadlock in Autofac](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2015/01/the-curious-case-of-deadlock-in-autofac.html).

> So to summarize, use the temporary container for resolving dependencies needed at construction time, but use the global container to resolve any run-time dependencies.

Another software design alternative is to not resolve the `ApplicationSettings` from the DI container inside the AutoMapper profile at all. Instead, the class that calls `IMapper.Map` could inject the `IOptions<ApplicationSettings>` via constructor injection and then either transform the `EmpDto.EmpUrl` in place or add a separate property like `EmpDto.EmpFullUrl` that adds the base domain prefix to an `EmpDto.EmpPath` property mapped verbatim from the `Emp.EmpPath` via AutoMapper.